# How do you perform standard redirection in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, redirect, file-io, io-redirection

I've written a bash script that through the command line you type: `bash bash_file.sh input_file.txt output_file.txt` and this works perfectly fine.  I've gotten it to work as it should where it reads the line from the input_file `Hello 10` and outputs the word `Hello` 10 times to `output_file.txt`.  That much is working.  Now, I can't figure out how to make the bash script handle this type of command line: `bash bash_file.sh < input_file.txt > output_file.txt`.  It's throwing all sorts of errors and I can't even begin to figure out a solution - if anybody has a solution or can point me in the direction of a solution that'd be great.

The code below works for the following command line command `bash bash_file.sh input_file.txt output_file.txt`.

```
string_word=$(<$1)

IFS=' '
read -ra ADDR <<< "$string_word"

num="${ARR[2]}"

str="${ARR[0]} ${ARR[1]}"

while [[ $num -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo $num
    echo "$str" >> $2
    num=$(( num - 1 ))
done
```

Now, I'm trying to modify it so the following command line command works on it: `bash bash_file.sh < input_file.txt > output_file.txt`

Comment: Do you know how to read data from the user and write it to screen? Just do that and you'll see that it insteads reads from input_file.txt and writes to output_file.txt when you redirect

Comment: We can't know what's wrong with your code if we can't see it. You could create a script that consists of just the command `cat`, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Or are you asking "how can I handle both files provided as parameter and reading from standard input otherwise?"

Comment: I've edited it to be more clear @BenjaminW. I think thatotherguy is onto something but I'm not entirely sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the errors in your script like how you read `ADDR` but reference `ARR`, you can generally just use `read` without a source to read from stdin, and `echo` without a redirection to write to stderr:

```
read -ra ARR

num="${ARR[1]}"
str="${ARR[0]}"

while [[ $num -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo "$str"
    num=$(( num - 1 ))
done
```

It works like this:

```
$ echo 'Hello 10' > input_file.txt
$ bash bash_file.sh < input_file.txt > output_file.txt
$ cat output_file.txt
Hello
Hello
Hello
[...]
```

You're also not required to redirect: you can now run it as `bash bash_file.sh`, enter `Hello 10` on the keyboard, and get the `Hello`s printed on screen, since that's the default stdin and stdout when you don't redirect.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my question - that worked :)